# Send GET request from Spring Boot to Java ServerSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, networking, socketserver

I need to communicate between a Spring Boot application and a Java ServeSocket. I have I created the Java ServerSocket and the Spring Boot.

Java ServerSocket has a `BufferedReader` as an input and `OutputStream` as a response.

I have just 2 questions:

1. How to send a Get Request from Spring Boot to a server?
2. How to send a Get Request from Spring Boot to Java ServerSocket, if the first method can be applied in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send a GET request is to use a high-level API. With Spring Boot this is currently [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.8/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html), which replaced the older [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) (see also tutorials such as: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient or https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/io.html#io.rest-client.webclient).

To call a server you need a URL such as `<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>`. As you say you want a GET call I assume you mean a HTTP GET call, which makes the  either `<scheme>` the protocol `http` or `https` and the `<scheme-specific-part>` takes the form `//<server-address>:<port>`. So in a simple scenario where you run the server socket on your localhost you could use something like `http://localhost:<port>/<path>`, where `<port>` is the port the ServerSocket listens to and `<path>` is the resource you want to GET.

Of course, a ServerSocket is very low-level. It's much more convenient to use either a higher-level API such as a [HttpServlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservlet) or a high-level API such as [RestController](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), which means to just provide another Spring Boot application for the server part.